# $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1+e^{-n})=^{?}$ and a series .

Tags: power-series, examples-counterexamples, infinite-product, exponential-sum

### Conjecture :

$$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1+e^{-n})=^{?}1/1!+1/2!+1/3!+0/4!+1/5!+1/6!+7/7!+5/8!+9/9!+7/10!+\cdots+a_n/n!+\cdots$$

Where $a_n$ is an integer such that :

$$0\leq a_n\leq n$$

> > Some arguments :

I think the best we can say is until we have the (says 20 because of floating point ) first term which seems true  currently more it goes more we have choice in the $a_n$ integers more the conjecture shall be true .

Another argument : if we stop to $a_k$ and take all the next terms equal to $n$ it seems always greater than the product .

> > Context :

For a context I was using the Engels form of $\ln 2$ which is near from the value of the product .
There is also the Jacobi theta function  as start for a formal proof .

> > Question :

How to (dis)prove the conjecture ?

> > Second question :

Following the comment what is the factoradic representation starting from $1!$ ?

Comment: I guess every real number has such an expansion in the factorial number system.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system

Comment: @Gary Thanks for the comment what about the constraint ?

Comment: @MissandMistercassouletchar Yes, in fact you take $0\le a_n < n$.

Comment: @Milten Thanks! sometimes it seems so obvious ...for your first comment it's $\leq n$

Comment: @MissandMistercassouletchar No, I meant you can actually take $0\le a_n\le n-1$. Which is because $\frac n{n!}=\frac 1{(n-1)!}$, so you would increase the previous digit instead. See also https://oeis.org/wiki/Factorial_numeral_system

Comment: This series is from this deleted [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4878379/905886)